# When can $L$ sets of the form $\{a,b,a+b\}$ partition $\{1,2,\dots, 3L\}$?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-optimization, extremal-combinatorics, set-partition, difference-sets

Now also posted to [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/455272/513693).

Consider a set of the form $\{a,b,a+b\}$ where $a$ and $b$ are *positive* integers with $b > a$. I will refer to such a set as a *triplet*. Consider now the problem of constructing $L$ *disjoint* triplets with as small a maximum element across them as we can manage. I will refer to a collection of $L$ disjoint triplets having the smallest maximum element across them as *optimal*. At best, the triplets will partition $\{1,2,\dots,3L\}$ giving a lower bound of $3L$ on the maximum element.

Here are some examples:

For $L = 1$, we have $\{1,2,3\}$ achieving the lower bound of $3 = 3L$.

For $L=2$, we have $\{1,3,4\}$, $\{2,5,7\}$ achieving $7 = 3L+1$.

It appears that this is optimal for $L=2$.

For $L=3$, we have $\{1,4,5\}$, $\{2,6,8\}$, $\{3,7,10\}$ achieving $10 = 3L+1$.

For $L=4$, we have $\{1,8,9\}$, $\{2,10,12\}$, $\{3,4,7\}$, $\{5,6,11\}$ achieving the lower bound of $12 = 3L$.

By random computer search, I was able to verify the existence of constructions with maximum element $3L+1$ for $L = 5,6,7$.

I am broadly interested in anything that would help with understanding this problem.

Can I always achieve $3L$ or $3L + 1$? If not, is there a good upper bound on the maximum element across $L$ disjoint triplets?

Ideally, I would hope that there is an explicit optimal construction hiding in the examples I've listed but I can't quite see the pattern.

Answer (score 3):

For $L=5$, optimal is $3L=15$, achieved by $$\{\{1,14,15\},\{2,10,12\},\{3,8,11\},\{4,5,9\},\{6,7,13\}\}.$$

For $L\in\{1,\dots,100\}$, I found via integer linear programming that optimal is $3L$ if $L \pmod 4\in\{0,1\}$ and $3L+1$ if $L \pmod 4\in\{2,3\}$.

---

By request, here's the ILP formulation I used.  Let $U$ be an upper bound on the elements.  For $L\le 100$, you can take $U=3L+1$.  Let $$T=\{(a,b,a+b): a \in \{1,\dots,U-1\}, b \in \{a+1,\dots,U-a\}\}$$ be the set of triplets.  Let binary decision variable $x_{a,b,c}$ indicate whether triplet $(a,b,c)$ is selected.  Let integer decision variable $z$ represent the maximum element used.  The problem is to minimize $z$ subject to linear constraints
\begin{align} 
z &\ge c\ x_{a,b,c} && \text{for $(a,b,c) \in T$} \tag1\label1 \\ 
\sum_{(a,b,c) \in T:\ i \in \{a,b,c\}} x_{a,b,c} &\le 1 && \text{for $i\in\{1,\dots,U\}$} \tag2\label2 \\
\sum_{(a,b,c) \in T} x_{a,b,c} &= L \tag3\label3 
\end{align}
Constraint \eqref{1} enforces the minimax objective.  Constraint \eqref{2} selects each element at most once.  Constraint \eqref{3} selects exactly $L$ triplets.

Because of \eqref{2}, you can strengthen \eqref{1} as
$$z \ge c\sum_{(a,b,c)\in T} x_{a,b,c} \quad \text{for $c\in \{3,\dots,U\}$ such that $(a,b,c) \in T$}$$

Alternatively, you can perform a bisection search for the minimum $U$, solving a sequence of feasibility problems (no objective) defined by \eqref{2} and \eqref{3}.

Comment: Note that $3L$ can't be achieved for $L\cong 2,3\pmod{4}$, because each triplet has an even sum and $1+2+\ldots+3L$ is odd for such $L$. So this is the best result we could hope for after taking into account the basic modular arithmetic restrictions.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating more on your integer linear programming search technique? I am interested in practical explicit construction methods as much as an existence proof.

Comment: I don't think that LP is the tool for this, but it would be interesting to know how close to unique these solutions are; there's not any immediately obvious structure in the given solution for L=5, but if there are many solutions at various L then the odds that a solution that generalizes can be found would seem to go up.